# ASP.NET Common Error Page Best Practises

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, azure

I am working on an ASP.NET web application. I am implementing the logging framework for the entire application.

web application has around 7-8 pages and is a simple CRUD operations web application.

Its an Azure hosted application. Following is the approach i am following for logging and exception handling.

1) Added Try...Catch blocks in the Data Access Layer, and Click events.

2) Upon catching errors, I am propagating the exceptions upto the Globabl.asax leve, and in Application_Error event logging the error into Event Logs and Trace Logs.

3) After this in the Global.asax file I am Redirecting to an Error Page to show a User Friendly Message and link to the failed page.

4) Just wanted to know whether is it a good approach to do this.

Thanks Friends.

Answer (score 1):

Are you actually handling exceptions on the DAL (ie, logging, trying to fix it, etc)? If not, then the try catch serves no purpose other than spinning cycles. The same is true for the click events, but it is not a bad practice to handle errors on the UI, even if you are not truly doing anything with them, as you will divert the user from the ugly error page to your own friendly message.

A single error page works fine, if you truly cannot handle the exception thrown. The upside is time to market, as you write precious little code to avoid showing the user an ugly message. The downside is the user misses context. I am not really up on the one size fits all exception handler, except as a backup (have an error I did not envision that got past my first line handler).

There is a variation of the common error page, if you are handling based on HTTP statuses and that is to use config.

Another pattern is to set up your own base page and have it work as an error handler. You can then set aside a container to fill when an error occurs. This approach works nicely for adding context, as the user still sees part of the page he was on, but you have given an error message, so he knows things have failed. I have seent this pattern used with a user control that is added to the container when an error occurs, but this is a bit more invovled, as you have to set up a table of codes and proper messages to show (which can be buggy in and of itself).

Answer (score 0):

Why not using ASP.NET custom error pages ? You can specify each error page for each status code or you can specify a default redirect.

You can configure this in the web config and you are all set.

```
 <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm" mode="On">
          <error statusCode="404" redirect="notfound.htm"/>
 </customErrors>
```

You can configure it for showing the custom error pages to all users or only to remote users etc..

http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages

I totally agree that you should log all errors in your catch block and write it to a log.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're kind of reinventing the wheel here. ASP.NET already includes things to help you achieve the desired result. Unless you need handling logic to cleanup after the errors, I wouldn't use try catch blocks. Have a look at the [ASP.NET Health Monitoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx) for logging errors. As far as presenting a custom error page see [How to create custom error reporting pages in ASP.NET by using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355).

Comment: No, I am not trying that for all standard 400+ and 500+ errors i am using ASP.NET custom error pages, however just for example DB connection is timed-out in that case if I don't have TRY CATCH at Data Access Layer, how would i come to know excpetion is occuring there.

Comment: So I have implemented a custom exception like DBException and thrown the same up to the Global.asax level, and based on the type I will display some message to user saying some issue with the DB connectivity of the server please let administrator know.

In case of something wrong in Click events, I will convery some issue with inputs. Please try again or contact administrator.

Is it a good approach?

Comment: Wrapping an exception in a custom exception is a perfectly acceptable approach if you are conveying addidtional information about the exception. However, the user doesn't need to know why it failed and should not be expected to convey that. If you've ever dealt with users directly, you know that they always forget what the message said anyway. That's why I'd suggest a standard error page and health monitoring. You can configure health monitoring to log error details. You can also configure health monitoring to send email when an exception occurs, which let's you address them more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think, You need not to use Exception Handling. Suppose You have a Presentation Layer and a Business Logic Layer/DataAccess Layer.

Upon facing the error in say Business Logic, it will move directly to Glogal.asax.cs file under Application_Error Event without going back to the calling function. Here you can log the error message like below....

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().InnerException.StackTrace
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().InnerException.Message
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().InnerException.Source
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().InnerException.TargetSite.DeclaringType.FullName
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().InnerException.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Name
HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().InnerException.TargetSite.DeclaringType.Namespace
```

---

Now in the Web Config you can write code to redirect the user on some default page like below.

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.htm" mode="On">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="ErrorPageNotFound.htm"/>
</customErrors>
```